# Number of items does not appear in the list of arrays

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Number of items does not appear in the list of arrays when sending to whatsapp. Only the item name and value. How could I solve it? Can someone help me?

When I click to send to whatsapp, the correct name and value is sent, but the quantity of the item is not informed. What am I doing wrong?

**CODE ONLINE:**

https://codepen.io/cinthia-danielle/pen/PoNQBdR

```
   <script>
        
        
        function displayCart() {
          var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
          
          var output = "";
          for(var i in cartArray) {
            output += `<tr>
         <td style="font-size:12px;"><strong>•</strong> ${cartArray[i].name}</td> 
         <td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn btn-primary menosItemCB' data-name='${cartArray[i].name}'>-</button>
         <input type='button' style="margin:2px; font-size:12px;" class='item-count form-control numberItemCB' data-name='${cartArray[i].name}' value='${cartArray[i].count}'><button style="margin-left: 4px;" class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon maisItemCB' data-name='${cartArray[i].name}'>+</button></div></td>
                = 
           <td style="font-size:12px;"> $ ${cartArray[i].total}<button class='delete-item btn btn-danger deleteItemCB' data-name='${cartArray[i].name}''>delete</button></td>
        </tr><br>`;
          }
          
          
          $('.send_form').on("click",function(){
        
        
    var input_blanter = document.getElementById('wa_name');
  
  /* Whatsapp Settings */
  var walink = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send',
    phone = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    walink2 = 'Cart Items';
  
  /* Smartphone Support */
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  var walink = 'whatsapp://send';
  }
  
  if("" != input_blanter.value){
  
   /* Call Input Form */
  var totalC = total.toFixed(2);
  
  /* Final Whatsapp URL */
  var blanter_whatsapp = walink + '?phone=' + phone + '&text=' + walink2 + '%0A%0A' +
    'Name : ' + input_name1 + '%0A%0A' + 'Cart: ' + totalC + '%0A%0A' + itemsCart  ;
  
  /* Whatsapp Window Open */
  window.open(blanter_whatsapp,'_blank');
  
  } 
  
  
  
    });
  
    
        }
        
    
        displayCart();
        
        
        
     </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

    
<table class="show-cart table"></table>

<form class="whatsapp-form">
  

  <input class="validate" id="wa_name" name="name" required="" type="text" value=''/>
  <label>Your Name</label>
  

  
  
  <a class="send_form" href="javascript:void" type="submit" title="Send to Whatsapp">Send to Whatsapp</a>
  
  </form>


</body>
```

**EDIT**

So far I tried to make the script work, but I couldn't. The list does not come with the number of items. I am a beginner and am unable to find an answer.

Comment: In your code posted above, which variable has an unexpected value? what value does it have and what did you expect?

Comment: @truculence I would like to send the name of the product, with the value and quantity chosen. The name and price appear in the message, but the quantity does not.

Comment: sure, i'm not as familiar with your code as you are so I don't know where that is supposed to happen in your code. which variable is supposed to contain the quantity? where in your code does it "get sent"?

Comment: @truculence I tried to make the "itemsCart" variable send the items listed on the cart. It only worked for the name and price. The list values ​​are sent to whatsapp.

Comment: Too much code here for us to try to figure out where your specific issue is, especially with very few debugging details given. Try to scale it down to only the relevant code that demonstrates the actual problem as per [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Hello, I reduced the code and left the part that I believe is not working.

Comment: @charlietfl When sending to whatsapp, the "${cartArray[i].count}" variable is not loaded.

Comment: I'm trying to load with the variable "itemsCart", but it's only working for "$ {cartArray[i].name}" and "$ {cartArray [i] .total}".

Comment: "$ {cartArray[i].count}" is not loaded :(

Comment: @truculence can you help me please?

Comment: The issue is that when you do `itemsCart = $(".show-cart").text()` is not retrieving the text of the button where your count shows, because is an `input.value`. I don't think the `.text()` is getting that becaus is not an `innerText`. Try to iterate over each `tr` and retrieve the value of the count using the `input.value` property.

Comment: @J.García ok, thanks a lot for the help, i will try to do that. :D

Comment: @J.García Is there an example of how to recover the value of a tr? Do you use the same method?

Comment: Is not the `tr` that is the issue, is the `input` where you store the count, you should get the `value` of that

Answer (score 2):

As commented before the issue is that when you use `.text()` to get your info, is not getting the amount of products because you are using an `input`.
In this case `innerText` will not contain any text, because the info you want to get is in the `input`'s `value` attribute.

The best way to go about this would be to build your itemsCart string from your variables in your javascript code and not from the html generated.
However if you want to do it like that, you should iterate over each `td` in a `tr`. And use the `value` attribute to get your amount of products, like so:

```js
itemsCart = $(".show-cart > tbody > tr").toArray().map(productItem => {
    let desc = $(productItem).children('td:nth-child(1)').text() + ',';
    desc += ' Amount: ' + $(productItem).find('td > div > input').val() + ',';
    desc += ' Price: ' + $(productItem).children('td:nth-child(3)').text();
    return desc;
}).join('\n')
```

Then add to your URL with :

```js
encodeURI(itemsCart)
```

that will yield:

```
%E2%80%A2%20Product%20three,%20Amount:%203,%20Price:%20$%2090.00%20%0A%E2%80%A2%20Product%20two,%20Amount:%201,%20Price:%20$%2020.00%20
```

which decoded is:

```
• Product three, Amount: 3, Price: $ 90.00 
• Product two, Amount: 1, Price: $ 20.00
```

I would also recommend not using `%0A`, just build your string as if you were to output that to console and then do `encodeURI(text)` to add it to your URL.
It will make your code much more readable.

PD:Also try to indent properly your code to make it more readable.

Comment: oww It worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the teachings and tips. Helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: BTW changed it to the jquery way of doing things. I made a mistake(not really familiar with jquery) on my first edit for that but now is fixed using `find(selector)` instead of `children(selector)` to get to the input.